# Create a new validating peer once user join blockchain

Tags: video-streaming, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I'm using hyperledger fabric to solve my *music streaming security* problem.

The *asset* in my project are *keys* that *encrypt/decrypt the mp3 files*. And those keys are stored in my ledger. Creators who upload the mp3 files to my media server, keep the keys about those mp3 files. So, *Every creator keep a their own ledger*. Ledgers are synchronized between the creator peers. And users who want to listen mp3 files will get the key from creator's ledger. So, one transaction is invoked, key is transferred from creator to user.

Should I create a new validating peer once a new creator/user join my blockchain network?

Comment: At right now, hyperledger fabric doesn't support to add a validating peer dynamically.

Comment: @scopionvn: When will hyperledger support  a validating peer to join dynamically?

Comment: I think when they release Hyperledger Fabric v1.0 on March 2017 or so.

Answer (score 1):

Hyperledger Fabric has evolved since the v0.6 release. With the release of v1.0.0, it now supports adding peers, organizations, users etc. Another change would be relevant to this system is the introduction of channels which permit the maintenance of independent ledgers. Hence, an artist could maintain their own ledger of their works and the keys would be inaccessible from other artists or users. Here's the information on the new [model](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fabric_model.html).